# Crash on close and quit

Tags: pyqt, pyside

I have a PySide application that hosts a VLC MediaPlayer instance within a QWidget. When the application is closed via the QMainWindow's close event, or by using QApplication.quit(), the UI disappears and then I get a Windows dialog "python.exe has stopped working".

The QApplication hosts a custom QMainWindow class, which contains a custom QWidget (which handles all the UI tasks, with QMainWindow handling messaging between threads - the app records keystrokes and writes output files in background threads). There is also a timer running the the main QWidget that updates a LineEdit with the current position in the video.

The crash happens whether files are being written or not (code commented out).

Do I need to be performing some type of garbage collection, or perhaps disposing of my objects in a specific order? I've tried stopping the timer, setting the MediaPlayer, the Instance, and the frame that hosts the MediaPlayer all to None, and then detroying the frame (self.videoFrame.destroy()), but the app still crashes.

The basic code was based on the example Qt application from vlc's repo [example](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=examples/qtvlc.py;h=34aeedce116e05f575eb0ebffdacf8f06db80402;hb=HEAD), which has no special garbage collection or disposal of objects.

I'm running Python 2.6 on Windows XP. Right now I run Python straight from the command line, but have it set up to create an exe with Py2Exe once I get this crash fixed.

Comment: Does that happen using PyQt or PySide or both? PySide has some known issues with objects lifetime.

Comment: PySide, I haven't tried with PyQt. I tagged the question with PyQt because the libraries are very similar. This does happen even if I open the application, start the video, and immediately shut the application.

Comment: Then I would suggest to try it with PyQt just to exclude the possibility of PySide bugs causing problems.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is late, but I did find a solution. In my case there was no memory leaks, but some of the QObjects must not have been closing properly. Python 3, PySide 1.2.1

```
class CustomWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def cleanUp(self):
        # Clean up everything
        for i in self.__dict__:
            item = self.__dict__[i]
            clean(item)
     # end cleanUp
# end class CustomWindow

def clean(item):
    """Clean up the memory by closing and deleting the item if possible."""
    if isinstance(item, list) or isinstance(item, dict):
        for _ in range(len(item)):
            clean(list(item).pop())
    else:
        try:
            item.close()
        except (RuntimeError, AttributeError): # deleted or no close method
            pass
        try:
            item.deleteLater()
        except (RuntimeError, AttributeError): # deleted or no deleteLater method
            pass
# end clean

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Qtgui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = CustomWindow()
    window.show()

    app.aboutToQuit.connect(window.cleanUp)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This will loop through everything that is in the main window, and it will close and delete all of the items found if possible. It made my application close immediately with no memory leaks or problems. You may also have to specifically close some items and make sure that no errors are caused from trying to delete an item that was already deleted.

**EDIT**

I eventually got rid of all the above clean up code with an event filter that called `QtGui.qApp.closeAllWindows()`. However, later the issue came up again. I now believe it has something to do with the C++ and python objects getting out of sync and how the objects are cleaned up.

```
class CloseAllFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    """Event filter for closing all windows if the widget is closed."""
    def eventFilter(self, receiver, event):
        results = super().eventFilter(receiver, event)
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Close and event.isAccepted():
            for win in QtGui.qApp.topLevelWidgets():
                if win != receiver:
                    try:
                        win.close()
                        # win.deleteLater() # This seemed to make python crash more consistently.
                    except (AttributeError, RuntimeError):
                        pass
        return results
# end class CloseAllFilter

window.__close_all_filter = CloseAllFilter()
window.installEventFilter(window.__close_all_filter )
```

This seemed to work better for me. I also have my application and window wrapped in a function.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did end up re-writing this in .Net, which I'm more familiar with, and don't really have the time to go back and integrate with the old code, so I can't mark whether or not this is the answer. If I ever return to it, I'll take a look and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: I tried and got this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:...gui.py", line 175, in <module>
    test_suite = SSITestSuiteGUI()
  File "C:...gui.py", line 141, in __init__
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(SSITesterThread.stop)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__pyqtSignature__'

Comment: My Solution isn't needed. PySide/PyQt has some referencing issue that causes python.exe to crash for me every once in a while. Your issue seems to be a PyQt4 issue where you are calling pyqtSignature when it doesn't exist.

Comment: This worked well for me, I didn't realise it but definitely helped me clean up objects. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Wrapping in function helped me

```
def main():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks,your answer helped me ,but can you explain why ?