# pyqt5 qml minimal example crashes on exit

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyqt5

I have this small example app that causes a crash.

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


def run():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(QUrl('main.qml'))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        return -1

    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
sys.exit(run())
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        selectFolder: true

        onAccepted: {
            console.log('activated')
        }
    }

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Open"
        onClicked: {
            fileDialog.open()
        }
    }
}
```

To cause the crash, simply open the app, click the button, select a directory, accept and then close the app.

The console shows a warning message:
`QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread`
and then the app just crashes. Any clues why or how to get an error message/stack trace?

Env: Windows 10, python 3.6.1, PyQt5 5.9

Comment: I ran into this issue and the only way I know to avoid crash is to create `FileDialog` dynamically [like this](https://gist.github.com/9dogs/2496f92e4d851330ce714797e69ff8fc). Would appreciate any ideas as well.

Comment: Yah, that didn't help either, but this seems to have 'solved' the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21614295/808727

Answer (score 0):

Before calling app.exec() you can add this line:

```
app.aboutToQuit.connect(lambda: app.closeAllWindows())
```

[Chris link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848436/pyqt5-qml-minimal-example-crashes-on-exit#comment78751245_45848436) helped with this problem. There is no more application crash on exit.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the fix is simple, just pass the `parent` parameter to `QQmlApplicationEngine()`:

```
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine(parent=app)
```

Comment: Little reminder: [stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if the answer is good for you :)